# What annual or quarterly maintenance do you do on your Linux Servers?

Tags: linux

What annual or quarterly maintenance do you do on your Linux Servers? Not including break fix and backups.

Comment: Great question - I've been wondering this myself.

Answer (score 5):

quarterly reboot [ usually with kernel upgrade ], checking if startup scripts ware not messed up and all required services get up properly.

HA / failover testing - take master down, check if slave kicks in, then the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

You **do not** want to do your backups quarterly. That should be done daily, or at most, weekly. If things break down, you will lose 3 months of work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

- Check filesystem usage (looking at trends via [ORCA](http://www.orcaware.com) or similar graphs) for things like out-of-control logs, etc.

  - Defragment XFS filesystems (xfs_fsr).

  - On multiuser systems, I'll kill stale sessions and leftover processes.

  - Clean out tmp directories, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. All scheduled maintenance is done monthly at the most, if not weekly or daily. We are in the server room often enough that they get dusted and cleaned more often than yearly or quarterly anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add in the few I know of:

1. Clean out any accumulated dust with compressed air (yearly)
2. Check logs manually to check for any abnormalities that log monitoring did not catch (quarterly/yearly)